# Can we read environment variables of child from parent process

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I know that fork will create a child process and then execve in the child process will execute  the program setting some environment variables.

My task here is, My parent process parent1 has initially created a child process Child1 following the fork/exec procedure and set an Environment variable "CHILD=first".

Later in the execution of parent process, I have created another child process 
Child2 following the same fork/exec procedure. This child2 has an environment variable set as "CHILD=second".

Now, later in the execution of parent process, I have to read all the environment variables of child1 and child2 from Parent1 for some operations based on the env values. Is it possible to read these child environment variables from parent process? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Use can check using any of `IPC` mechanisms like pipe,..

Comment: Why not just hold "child state" within the parent?

Comment: Why do you want this?  The parent should maintain interesting information about its children in its own data structure, probably indexed by process ID.

Comment: See [Q&A here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process).

Answer (score 1):

You can read the environment from `/proc/<pid>/environ`, on Linux. The variables are separated by nul-characters.

Comment: The values in `/proc/<pid>/environ` are not updated dynamically, but display only the initial environment of the process.  It is not clear to me from the question whether the value of CHILD is set pre-fork or only in the child, so reading `/proc/<pid>/environ` may not be useful.

Comment: Hmm, in that case he's gonna need IPC, via pipes, files, or shared memory.